# Pandas: Evenly allocate/assign data from one Dataframe to another over multiple users

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe of Account Managers IDs and a total of their allocated accounts **(df_am)**:

```
    account_manager_id     account_total
0   1                      8
1   2                      3
2   3                      3
3   4                      1
4   5                      7
5   6                      2
```

I have a second Dataframe of accounts to be allocated to an account manager **(df_poc)**:

```
    point_of contact   account_no 
0   John               100
1   Bob                78 
2   Sally              125
3   Greg               128
4   Bret               78 
5   Corey              100
6   Chad               100
7   Mavis              8
8   Andre              632
9   Hunter             157
10  Debra              12
```

I need to evenly allocate the accounts to an account manager, note that account_no can have multiples of the same with different point_of_contact as such these will need to be allocated to the same account_manager_id.

In order to do this I'm looking to check the unique account_no in df_poc and allocate it to the account manager who has the lowest total in account_total then count the totals again and move on to the next account_no.

For example account_manager_id 4 will get the first account_no as they only have 1 account so far. As it's account_no 100 and there are 3 pocs account_manager_id 4 will get all 3 bringing their total to 4.

This would make account_manager_id 6 the lowest on 2 and account_no 78 will be allocated to them.

We now have 3 account managers with 3 accounts (2, 3, 6) I have no preference here, so I will just allocate it to the first account_manager. Bringing account_manager_id 2 up to 4, leaving 3 and 6 still on 3 so on and so forth.

I truly hope you can see what I am trying to achieve. If you have a better solution please let me know.

**Desired outcome, df_am:**

```
    account_manager_id     account_total
0   1                      8
1   2                      5
2   3                      5
3   4                      5
4   5                      7
5   6                      5
```

**Desired outcome, df_poc:**

```
    point_of contact   account_no   account_manager_id
0   John               100          4
1   Bob                78           6
2   Sally              125          2
3   Greg               128          3
4   Bret               78           6
5   Corey              100          4
6   Chad               100          4
7   Mavis              8            2
8   Andre              632          3
9   Hunter             157          4
10  Debra              12           6
```

As you can hopefully see account_managers 8 and 5 never got a single account in order for the other account_managers to catch up on their totals.

I've been using using a loop (iterrows) with .min to get the account manager to allocate, however this approach would not take in to consideration multiple account_no and would lead to accounts being split over multiple account_managers.

```
lowest = df_am[df_am["account_total"] == df_am["account_total"].min()]  #to get lowest total
lowest = lowest.iloc[:1]  #keep first account manager if multiples on same total
```

Thank you any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, I created a new dataframe of unique account_no and counted the point_of_contact for the account.

```
    account_no  counts
0   100         3
1   78          2
2   125         1
3   128         1
4   8           1
5   632         1
6   157         1
7   12          1
```

Then I did an iterrow on the new df (df_check):

```
for i, row in df_check.iterrows():                                          #do not like using iterrow but see alternative
    account = row["account_no"]
    count = row["counts"]
    lowest = df_am[df_am["account_total"] == df_am["account_total"].min()]  #get the account manager will the fewest accounts
    lowest = lowest.iloc[:1]                                                #if more than one with fewest this ensure there is always one account manager
    lowest["account_no"] = account                                          #add the account number to assign to the account manager
    new_count = lowest["account_total"]                                    #takes the total accounts for the account
    lowest = lowest.drop(["account_total"], axis=1)                         #drop from df as we no longer need this.
    user = lowest["account_manager_id"].astype('int')
    df_check.at[i, "id"] = user                                          #assigns the account manager with the fewest accounts to the account
    new_count = new_count + count                                        #takes the account managers old total and adds the account count giving them a new total
    df_am.at[user, "account_total"] = new_count                          #adds the new total to the account manager
```